# How to return a value from std::map<int, std::string> with a uint64_t key type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, key-value, stdmap

Novice question, but I searched for this and couldn't find something clearly solving my issue - apologies if this is obvious.

I have defined a map which looks like this:

```
map<int, string> testmap = {
    { 0, "a" },
    { 1, "b" },
    { 2, "c" }
}
```

However, I need to retrieve a value from `testmap` using a `uint64_t` value provided by another function.

When I do `testmap[my_uint64_t_value]` it returns an empty string, so I think this is because it's adding `my_uint64_t_value` as a *key* and setting the *value* to `NULL`.

This is the same if I set the map type to `<uint64_t, string>`, at least the way I'm currently defining my keys.

However, is there a way that I either:

1. convert the `uint64_t` value to a regular `int`
2. define the map as `<uint64_t, string>`, and be able to define my
   keys as the 'correct' type?

It seems like `int` type conversion isn't that common, is this something that should be avoided?

Comment: You should provide a complete source code example. We have not enough information to really determine, what the problem is. I assume that there simply is no key with the value of `my_uint64_t_value`.

Comment: And regarding integer conversion: Turn on compiler warnings to a warning for dangerous conversions. Of course you always have to be aware of possible overflow when casting from a larger to a smaller type, and more problems when casting between signed and unsigned integer values.

Comment: test with but you have to know it's dangerous, read about range of int, etc.  testmap[static_cast<int>(my_uin64_t_value)]

Comment: In this example, does it works like expected? http://cpp.sh/7p3k5 Be aware of what jamek wrote, for testing things it might be ok but when you do this with serious data that can quickly exceed the int in the map you will end up with some funny behaving program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get an empty string is [std::map::operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) returns a reference to the value **if and only if it exists**, otherwise it performs an **insertion**. I suspect you have the latter case.

You need to use [std::map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) for search.

```
uint64_t keyToFind =  1;
if (auto iter = testmap.find(keyToFind); iter != testmap.cend()) 
{
   // do something
   std::cout << "Found!\n";
}
else { std::cout << "Not Found!\n"; }
```

Like @Rene mentioned in the comments, casting from `uint64_t` to `int` can cause overflow. Therefore, making the key to larger type(as per requirement) would be a good idea.

```
std::map<uint64_t, std::string> testmap;
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in another answer, the `[]` operator of the map class will perform an insertion with a default-constructed value if the key is not present in the map.

You can first use the `count` method to determine if the key is present in the map before accessing it.

```
if(testmap.count(keyToFind))
    return testmap[keyToFind];
else
    report_key_not_found();
```

An alternative solution is to use the [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) method to access the value. It will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception if the key is not present instead of inserting a new key.

Comment: `map::find` allow one look-up as alternative to `at`.